# Why is the Association Bonus not showing up as privilege in the Help Center?

Tags: discussion, privileges, help-center, association-bonus

Why is qualifying for the association bonus (at 200 reputation) not mentioned in the [privileges list in the Help Center](/help/privileges)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the purpose of the Help Center to list *all* privileges. One could even question if this is a privilege at all, since all you get is more reputation. In any case, many more privileges are missing, e.g.

- With 150 reputation you can vote in an election
- With 2000 reputation you don't get a popup asking to comment when downvoting a post

For a complete list of privileges and corresponding levels, see the FAQ [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/295232).

Comment: Moderators do not get all the privileges on that list: Half of the “established user” privilege is to have an expanded user card, which is only given at 1k rep (as low rep diamond employees don’t have it).

Comment: Oh, you're right about that. The two examples I mentioned (voting in an election and the downvote popup) are two other things ♦ moderators don't automatically get.

Comment: Maybe you should make it clearer that all privileges are not listed in that help center  list.